# Does there exist commands to recognize devices?

Tags: windows-7

Is there a command to initiate recognition of an USB device? How about a device that is connected by ethernet rj-45 or by serial port?

I've already tried Device Manager and anything else I could think of using GUI-wise.

I was thinking there might be some command to enter at the Command Prompt.

Devices are recognized by other computers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to do, but you may be able to do it with [**DevCon**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272).  <strike>Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a x64 version, so I have not used it for some time</strike>.

There is a link to the x64 version [here](http://munashiku.slightofmind.net/20090621/sometimes-64-bit-is-a-pain).

Comment: It should be part of windows driver kit, and there should be x64 version available in the kit. I remember that I used it on 64 bit version of 7.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: Yeh, I found a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

On the device manager, there is option to detect devices. There should be a row of small icons on the top of the screen. One of them will have a computer and a magnifying glass. It's for device detection.

[image: Circled icon will start hardware scan.]

You can also right-click on the computer on the device manager and scan for hardware changes.

Comment: @Moab  I have it.

Comment: Ok, I always use >right click on Computer >manage, it does not show when you access DM this way, thanks for the screen shot.